# Do employers ask to see source files in interviews / presentations?

Tags: presentation-design

I have my first interview for a UI/UX position in a week and I'm wondering how I should prepare. They want to see a portfolio and I'll have to present some things, so I'm kind of nervous.

I'm wondering if I should clean up some of my source files in case they want to see them, but I'm unsure if that's a standard practice? I'd rather spend time preparing my presentation and going over mock interviews, but I don't want to leave any stone unturned.